# How to fix errors reported by DBCC CHECKDB

Tags: sql-server, dbcc-checkdb

I am getting a lot of errors from `DBCC CHECKDB`, including:

> Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1
>   
> Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 3667181342891245568 (type Unknown), page (7791:-1694668604). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 133129 and -12.
>   
>   
> Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   
> Object ID 405576483, index ID 73, partition ID 72057594049200128, alloc unit ID 72057594054246400 (type In-row data): Page (1:194923) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
>   
>   
> Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   
> Table error: Object ID 405576483, index ID 73, partition ID 72057594049200128, alloc unit ID 72057594054246400 (type In-row data). Page (1:194923) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:186194) and previous (1:194922) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
>   
>   
> Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   
> Table error: Object ID 405576483, index ID 73, partition ID 72057594049200128, alloc unit ID 72057594054246400 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:186194), slot 103 refers to child page (1:194924) and previous child (1:194923), but they were not encountered.
>   
>   
> Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   
> Table error: Object ID 405576483, index ID 73, partition ID 72057594049200128, alloc unit ID 72057594054246400 (type In-row data). Page (1:194932) is missing a reference from previous page (1:194931). Possible chain linkage problem.

Most importantly, at the end, the following is relayed:

> CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 28 consistency errors in database 'houseme'.
>   
>   
> repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (houseme).

What do I do?

Comment: added last part, is that what ur looking for? database backups are not an option..(dont ask why) :D

Comment: Of course they aren't. Most people don't care about backups until they need them and it's too late. This is like getting in a car accident, going to the hospital, and then trying to put on your seatbelt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output of `DBCC CHECKDB` has told you exactly what to do:

```
USE [master];
GO

ALTER DATABASE houseme SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
DBCC CHECKDB(N'houseme', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS);
ALTER DATABASE houseme SET MULTI_USER;
```

In case the name of the option isn't obvious enough, this *can lead to data loss* - but without backups, you don't really have any other choice.

If this doesn't work, and you don't have backups, well, you may have just learned a very expensive lesson about why you should have backups. You can see if [Paul Randal has some other ideas](https://www.google.com/search?q=dbcc+checkdb+site%3Asqlskills.com), or [this idea from Steve Stedman](http://stevestedman.com/2015/04/introducing-the-database-corruption-challenge-dbcc-week-1-challenge). No guarantees, of course.

If you still have consistency errors after multiple tries, it might be time to create a new database, migrate as much *consistent* data as you can, and cut your losses.

Comment: There are options for repair without data loss, when no backups exist. Even if you must use REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS there are steps you can take before hand to limit that loss [Steve Stedman has some ideas](https://www.google.com/search?q=dbcc+checkdb+site%3Astevestedman.com)

Comment: @James Do you have a more specific link? That's just a set of 217 search results on his site for checkdb

Comment: I was following your example in the Paul Randal link :) here is [an example.](http://stevestedman.com/2015/04/introducing-the-database-corruption-challenge-dbcc-week-1-challenge) Brent Ozar solved it with no backups and no data loss P.S. This comes from the 2017 PASS presentation, which I am just now watching and found this SE post while problem solving.

Comment: Okay, thanks... there is a difference, of course, but I'm not going to bother.